# How to stringify a tree model

Tags: treemodel

I am working with `treemodel` to create a tree representation
When I try to stringify it using json, or to string, I get an error of course.

What is the best way to stringify this tree model?

Here is example of my output

```
    config:
   { childrenPropertyName: 'children',
     modelComparatorFn: undefined },
  model:
   { name: 0,
     content:
      { questions: [Array],
        results: [],
        varName: 'Step #1',
        attributes: [Array],
        type: 'default',
        contentElements: [] },
     children:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  children:
   [ Node {
       config: [Object],
       model: [Object],
       children: [],
       parent: [Circular] },
```

Comment: you mean `treemodel.js`?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to output TreeModel Js model as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765667/how-to-output-treemodel-js-model-as-json)?

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes. Thank you